# Zykov algorithm

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings

The following question regarding the grahph colouring algorithm by Zykov might be trivial to a specialist in this field (which I'm not).

Zykov algorithm says that given a graph G its chromatic number satisfies 
$X(G)=\min\{X(G/uv), X(G+uv)\}$. The procedure is repeated until we end up with complete graphs and the chromatic number is equal to the smallest complete graph that is obtain this way.

Now my question is the following: Can we always choose vertices u,v in the graph G in such a way that $X(G)=X(G/uv)$, t.i. we can alway get to the chromatic number of G using only contractions by smartly choosing the verices? Or is there a trivial counterexample?

(I am aware that this might not make sense if one would like to use it for the algorithm since choosing a suitable pair of vertices might be time consuming.)

Answer (score 4):

Take an optimal colouring and then repeatedly choose pairs in colour classes.

This is of course only efficient if P equals NP, but that’s true of any procedure to do what you want.